# Find/Sed not working as expected

Tags: linux, sed

So essentially I want to understand why this command- sent to terminal as a one-liner doesn't work as intended.  It runs for several minutes but my test files containing "teststring1" don't get replaced.  Please without radically changing the syntax or asking why I am doing this from root, can anyone identify the reason why it doesn't?

```
cd /tmp;find / -maxdepth 3 -type f -print0 | xargs -0 sed -i 's/teststring1/itworked!/gI'
```

Comment: Shell is interpreting the exclamation mark (!) , try without that?

Comment: ok trying now, will update results in a few minutes

Comment: why bother changing to /tmp, your find command uses '/' which anchors your search at the root dir. /tmp will be searched, but if you intend to search /tmp and below (your -maxdepth 3), then either use `cd /tmp; find . -maxdepth ...` OR more simply, `find /tmp -maxdepth ...` , without the initial `cd /tmp;` . Good luck.

Comment: @ shellter- I want to search from "/". I have experienced problems in the past running this command from other directories, and so I now Cd to /tmp first.

Comment: @ Ismail, so this didnt change anything taking the ! out, any other ideas guys?

Comment: Find will start from '/' whether you're in '/', '/tmp, '/some/big/long/path/to/some/application/log/dir'. AND I can well imagine that if you apply sed to `/bin/ls` (for example, which would be returned by your find command as stated), you're going to have problems. Can't you limit your search to a reasonable starting dir, used in the find cmd, AND add something like `-name '*.txt'`? Better to leave out the sed pipeline until you understand the find results and get that fixed. Good luck.

Comment: So im sorry but I am sure that it does matter where the command is run, this is due to numerous test previously. I think its a quirk with the program then, and not the syntax. Thanks for your help anyway mate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Citate from `man sed`:

```
If  no  -e,  --expression, -f, or --file option is given, then the first non-option argument is taken as the sed script to interpret.  All remaining arguments are names of input files; if no input files are specified, then the standard input is read.

s/regular expression/replacement/flags  
The value of flags in the substitute function is zero or more of the following:
- N       Make the substitution only for the N'th occurrence of the regular expression in the pattern space.
- g       Make the substitution for all non-overlapping matches of the regular expression, not just the first one.
- p       Write the pattern space to standard output if a replacement was made.  If the replacement string is identical to that which it replaces, it is still considered to have been a replacement.
- w file  Append the pattern space to file if a replacement was made.  If the replacement string is identical to that which it replaces, it is still considered to have been a replacement.
```

So `find / -maxdepth 3 -type f -print0 | xargs -0 sed -e 's/[tT][eE][sS][tT][sS][tT][rR][iI][nN][gG]1/itworked!/g' -i` will work as you want.

If you do not like ugly pattern for case insensitive matches, you can use perl instead of sed: `find / -maxdepth 3 -type f -print0 | xargs -0 perl -pe 's/teststring1/itworked!/ig' -i`